# how to reduce high Cpu Usage in emgu.cv RTSP Player?

Tags: c#, memory, cpu, rtsp, emgucv

im novice developer using c#. I made User Control for playing rtsp from emgu.cv. I used this user control for my main program for playing 9 rtsp. but when i used my user control 9 times, it makes my cpu overflow, more than 70% cpu usage, also 1.3GB memory usage. i don't know what's wrong with my code. please help me anyone used emgu.cv in c#. it doesn't matter when playing only one rtsp.
also tell me if my code seems bad, how to fix it!
i don't know reason. please help me as fast as you can!
this is my code

```
capture = new VideoCapture(rtspUrl, VideoCapture.API.Ffmpeg);
capture.SetCaptureProperty(CapProp.Fps, frame);
capture.Start();

Task.Run(async () =>
{
    while (isPlaying)
     {
            UpdateFrame();
            await Task.Delay(1000 / frame);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
      });
}


using (Mat frame = new Mat())
     {
          capture.Retrieve(frame, 0);
          if (!frame.IsEmpty)
          {
               using (Image<Bgr, byte> image = 
               frame.ToImage<Bgr, byte>())
               {
                   lock (captureLock)
                   {
                        try
                        {
                            if (!isRecording && videoWriter !=null)
                                    videoWriter.Dispose();
                            else if (isRecording && videoWriter != null)
                                {
                                    if(frame!=null)
                                        videoWriter.Write(frame);
                                }
                            }
                            catch (System.AccessViolationException) { }
                        }
                pictureBoxRTSP1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>pictureBoxRTSP1.Image = image.ToBitmap()));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why do you double-check `isPlaying`?

Comment: it was i mistake. i fixed it

Comment: `if(frame!=null)` doesn't make sense to me. If it _was_ `null`, then the call to `frame.ToImage` should have resulted in a NullReferenceException. Also: `catch (System.AccessViolationException) { }` - I hope that's just for brevity in the question. You should _never_ have an empty `catch` ( with rare exceptions, where you should leave a comment about _why this is intentionally empty in that case_ ).

Comment: You are also checking `videoWriter != null` twice. That's unnecessary. Yes, also a micro-optimization, but in a high-freq setting it might have _some_ impact.

Comment: And you _really_ need to work on those indentations. Your IDE can fix that for you. If it is messed up like this, you are asking for errors. Fixing it will improve readablity and it is really _one_ combo-keypress, so there is no excuse.

Comment: @Fildor: Hopefully some indentation problems are an artifact of copy/paste from source with a wider tab-width than SO.  In emacs, `M-x untabify` will turn tabs into spaces.

Comment: @PeterCordes That may well be the case. Anyway, OP should be aware indentation needs to be fixed, here, too or he will always be downvoted for it. And that's a really avoidable reason to be dved.

Comment: thank you for every comment. but i want reason why my high cpu and memory  usage. also how to solve it. i used (frame != null) because i met AccessViolationException sometimes at videowriter.write(frame). it even cannot catch exception.

Comment: using (Image<Bgr, byte> image = 
               frame.ToImage<Bgr, byte>())    I think this part causes high cpu and memory,  do you have any opinions?